# Hibernate - @Formula problem with camelcase tables

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using a query inside `@Formula`, but my table "MyTableB" in the from clause is in camelcase, therefore I have to use double quotes to identify the table, but I have this problem.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "my_table_a" )
public class MyTableA {

    [...]

    @Column( name = "id_my_table_b" )
    private Long idMyTable;

    @Formula( "( SELECT tb.description FROM \"MyTableB\" tb WHERE tb.id = id_my_table_b LIMIT 1 )" )
    private String descriptionTableB;

}
```

Result query:

```
select
    [...],
    (
    select
        tb.description
    from
        ta."MyTableB" tb
    where
        tb.id = id_my_table_b
    limit 1 ) as c1,
from
    my_table_a ta
where
    ta.id = ?
```

My problem is in clause from of the subquery, that put a `ta."MyTableB"`, and it's not a column of my_table_a, but a table.

Ps.: I'm using postgresql.

Comment: Perhaps you can use UESCAPE to change to another escape character than double-quote?

Comment: I don't know, I have tried to add `'\u0022' + "MyTableB" + '\u0022'` in the @Formula, but the same problem occurred.

Comment: Hibernate will always add the table alias in the formula if there is no alias. I'm not sure if a select in a formula will ever work

Comment: I didn't mean that you should add '\u0022' I meant that you should remove the quotes and define another escape character: #MyTableB# with UESCAPE '#' for example.

Comment: Do you know how can I do this @ewramner?

Comment: Check the documentation and run the query standalone (i.e. not from code but from a SQL prompt). You should be able to slap UESCAPE on to the existing SQL. Then, when it works, try it in the formula. I don't have a PostgreSQL database to experiment at present.